SQL View (or query) to show cumulative sum over time
Let's assume I have the following data in an SQL table called transactions with primary keys tx_date, location, item:
tx_date       location    item         quantity    fee
2024-01-01    US          ITEM.123         1000     20
2024-02-04    EMEA        ITEM.456789       600     12
2024-03-09    US          ITEM.123         -750    -30
2024-04-12    EMEA        ITEM.456789       700     25
2024-05-16    EMEA        ITEM.456789      -800    -35

How can I create a view that shows the net_quantity and net_fee of each (location, item) pair on each tx_date? Effectively, the cumulative sum over time:
tx_date       location    item        net_quantity   net_fee
2024-01-01    US          ITEM.123            1000        20
2024-02-04    EMEA        ITEM.456789          600        12
2024-03-09    US          ITEM.123             250       -10
2024-04-12    EMEA        ITEM.456789         1300        37
2024-05-16    EMEA        ITEM.456789          500         2


WITH CumulativeSums AS (
SELECT
    tx_date,
    location,
    item,
    quantity,
    fee,
    SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY location, item ORDER BY tx_date) AS net_quantity,
    SUM(fee) OVER (PARTITION BY location, item ORDER BY tx_date) AS net_fee
FROM
    transactions
)
SELECT
    tx_date,
    location,
    item,
    net_quantity,
    net_fee
FROM
    CumulativeSums
ORDER BY
    location,
    item,
    tx_date;


